# What will be the new features available in ASP.Net 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

What will be the new features available in ASP.Net 4.0?

Comment: Key features? The same ones in ASP.NET 1 - 3.5. (You probably meant key *new* features) ;)

Comment: @Mark Brackett: you are correct, I mean new features, but now I edited it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a couple of videos on Mircosoft Channel 9:

- [ASP.NET 4.0 Roadmap](https://web.archive.org/web/20100328163517/http://channel9.msdn.com:80/pdc2008/PC20/) by Scott Hunter
  It seems like someone has made [session notes](https://web.archive.org/web/20210119052326/http://geekswithblogs.net/evjen/archive/2008/10/27/126250.aspx) on this talk, as well.
- [New Features of ASP.NET 4.0](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/The+Knowledge+Chamber/Stephen-Walther-New-Features-of-ASPNET-40/) by Steven Walther

---

Quoted (partially) from those session notes on the linked blog post:

**Web Forms**

- Developers can manage control IDs that affect rendered client ID
- Remove ID bloat, and 'mangling'
- CSS:
  - Ideally remove the need to use CSS adapters
  - Defer to CSS styles and bypass existing style properties
    - non-inline style attributes
  - Support non-table-based HTML rendering
- URL-routing for web forms
  - Friendly url handling for web forms
  - configuration model for url routing
- View state
  - Disable on the page, enable on specific controls - they will provide granular control
                of viewstate - today it is backwards
  - Disable on control, enable on child controls
  - GridView/ListView work better without viewstate
- ASP.NET dynamic-data

**Ajax**

- Continue ASP.NET Ajax innovation : RIA
- Appeal to JavaScript Developers
- Provide support for the page developer
- jQuery including Intellisense
- Templates and data binding
  - Client side handling, REST or Web Services
  - Covers page developer and component developer scenarios
- DOM manipulation, selectors ...
- Ajax higher-level components
  - Ajax Control Toolkit is a part of the strategy - they will make the toolkit part
                of the overall ASP.NET package
  - New controls
- Centralized script libraries and break-up for performance

**ASP.NET MVC**

- Appeal to those wanting separation of concerns, TDD, full control
- Ruby on Rails, Django, PHP
- Building on from ASP.NET MVC 1.0
- ASP.NET MVC (Model View Controller)
- Asynchronous controllers
- Sub-controllers & Views
- Declarative controls

**ASP.NET Core**

- Address customer pain points
- Improve scale and performance
- Cache extensibility and performance:
  - Enable caching like Velocity

Answer (score 5):

There are quite a few:

- static client-side ID's
- better dynamic data support
- better support for the routing feature (made popular by ASP.NET MVC) for webforms apps
- many Ajax enhancements

Read Scott Hanselman's excellent blog post (series) on .NET 4 [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASP4WhirlwindTourAroundNET4AndVisualStudio2010Beta1.aspx).

And checkout a great whitepaper on ASP.NET 4.0 [here](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet40/).

Marc

Answer (score 4):

[Microsoft White Paper on ASP.NET 4.0](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet40/)

This has a very thorough breakdown and explanation of what to look forward to.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ASP.NET 4.0 articles on this blog - [.NET 4.0](http://www.dotnetcube.com/?tag=/.net+4.0)