# What all are the New features in asp.net 4.0.?

Tags: .net, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What will be the new features available in ASP.Net 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894543/what-will-be-the-new-features-available-in-asp-net-4-0)

What all are the New features in asp.net 4.0.? Currently our team is doing project on .net 2.0 and we didn't go for an upgrade on asp.net 3.5. Now we are preparing to switch from asp.net 2.0 to asp.net 4.0. A list of such features would help us in designing the training program.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894543/what-will-be-the-new-features-available-in-asp-net-4-0

Comment: Jorn the list is outdated as many pointed entries are on rc version and are 1 yr old !

Comment: Then that question and it's answers should be updated to reflect any changes rather than asking a new question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below are my notes (with links) of an internal presentation I'm doing. This is by no means an exhaustive list, but it's an oveview in the areas that interest me. I've highlighted a few of my personal favourites :)

For a more official list, see [Håvard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184196/what-all-are-the-new-features-in-asp-net-4-0/2184224#2184224).

**Edit:** Just realised you only mentioned ASP.NET 4, but I'll leave the other items in there for anyone who is interested.

- [CLR](http://blogs.msdn.com/maoni/archive/2008/11/19/so-what-s-new-in-the-clr-4-0-gc.aspx)

  - [In-process Side-by-Side](http://blogs.msdn.com/clrteam/archive/2009/12/01/clr-inside-out-in-process-side-by-side.aspx)
  - [Code Access Security deprecated in favour of Security Policy](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2009/05/27/coding-with-security-policy-in-net-4-0-implicit-uses-of-cas-policy.aspx)
  - [Type Equivalence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997297(VS.100,lightweight).aspx) (noPIA)
- Languages

  - [C#](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfuture)

    - `dynamic` keyword
    - Named / optional arguments
    - [Co/contra-variance support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183(VS.100).aspx) in delegates and interfaces
  - VB.NET

    - Auto Properties
    - Lambdas with no return value
    - Multi-line lambdas
    - Collection Initializers
    - Automatic Line Continuations
  - [F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/fsharp/default.aspx)
  - [Dynamic Language Runtime](http://dlr.codeplex.com/)

    - [IronRuby](http://ironruby.codeplex.com/) (out of band release)
    - [IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPython/)
- [BCL](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2009/10/21/what-s-new-in-the-bcl-in-net-4-beta-2-justin-van-patten.aspx)

  - [Parallel Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/concurrency/default.aspx)
  - [**Code Contracts**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx)
  - [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://www.codeplex.com/MEF)
  - [**Reactive Extensions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) (IObservable)
  - Location / GPS APIs
  - [Memory Mapped Files](http://blogs.msdn.com/salvapatuel/archive/2009/06/08/working-with-memory-mapped-files-in-net-4.aspx)
  - Large Numbers (BigInteger, Complex Numbers)
  - Tuples / SortedSet
  - ObservableCollection moved to System.dll
  - Lots of random, helpful, API changes:

    - Enum.HasFlag
    - Enum.TryParse
    - Stream.CopyTo(Stream)
    - Guid.TryParse
    - **IEnumerable File.EnumerateFiles()**
    - IEnumerable File.ReadLines()
    - String.Join(IEnumerable)
    - String.Concat(IEnumerable)
- ASP.NET

  - **[<%: %> Encoding Syntax](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/09/25/html-encoding-code-nuggets.aspx)**
  - [Clean web.config files](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/25/clean-web-config-files-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)
  - [**Web.config merge/deployment**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(VS.100).aspx)
  - [Extensible Output Caching](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/27/extensible-output-caching-with-asp-net-4-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) (OutputCacheProvider)
  - [SEO improvements](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/05/asp-net-4-seo-improvements-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) (access to page metadata)
  - [**ASP.NET MVC 2**](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/10/asp-net-mvc-2.aspx)

    - Areas (Admin areas)
    - Validation (annotations; support for jquery)
    - Type templates
  - ASP.NET WebForms

    - [Routing support](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)
    - [Cleaner, configurable client IDs](http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx)
    - [Smaller viewstate](http://weblogs.asp.net/despos/archive/2009/06/13/asp-net-4-0-more-control-on-viewstate-management.aspx)
- [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588(VS.100).aspx) ([also](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/26/wpf-4-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx))

  - Windows 7 Multitouch
  - Windows 7 Shell integration (Taskbar windows, taskbar progress)
  - [Improved Text Rendering](http://blogs.msdn.com/text/archive/2009/08/24/wpf-4-0-text-stack-improvements.aspx)
  - Cached Compositions
  - Pixel Shader 3
  - DLR databinding support
  - New XAML/BAML parser
  - Visual State Manager (from Silverlight)
- [Silverlight 4](http://silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight-4-beta/)

  - Multitouch + gestures
  - Printing support
  - CoreCLR / CLR compatability (single compilation)
  - Webcam / Microphone Support
  - Mousewheel support
  - Official Google Chrome support
  - 200% faster (supposedly)
  - H.264
  - Video streaming support
  - Out-of-browser applications

    - Host HTML
    - Toast (bubble) notifications
    - Window chrome customisations
  - Trusted out-of-browser applications

    - User folder read-write access (my documents, etc)
    - COM automation
    - Privilage elevation dialog
- [Entity Framework 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723.aspx)

  - **Completely Rewritten**
  - Persistance Ignorance / POCO Support

    - Comparison or virtual members
  - Model-first / Database Generation Support
  - T4 Code Generation
  - Lazy Loading
  - "Client" entities that track their own changes
  - Code-only developer support (no edmx xml)
- [Workflow Foundation 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx)

  - Completely rewritten
  - XAML (codeless) design
  - Limited BC with WF3
- [Visual Studio .NET 2010 IDE](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010/default.mspx)

  - Static Code Analysis (class coupling, etc)
  - [Multi-targeting](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/27/multi-targeting-support-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx)
  - [Multiple Monitor Support](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/31/multi-monitor-support-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx)
  - Task debugging support (task stack visualisation)
  - [Add Reference dialog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/29/add-reference-dialog-improvements-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) defaults to *Project*; *.NET* tab is asynchronous
  - Code navigation (CTRL+COMMA to find resource by name)
  - Editor written in WPF / MEF
  - No more "team" editions. Only Professional, Premium and Ultimate
  - "Data Dude": redistributable command line for comparing and updating databases (Premium/Ultimate)
  - Test features: ability to record video + steps of bugs for reproduction (Premium/Ultimate)
  - [Web Deployment Tool](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/346/web-deployment-tool/)

Comment: +1 for creating an exhaustive list and covering .net 4.0 as a whole. Do keep it updated for any new feature or change in existing.

Comment: please do update the list for any new updations.

Comment: are there any new updates ? Please share...

Answer (score 3):

Plase see [this whitepaper from Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/LEARN/whitepapers/aspnet4/default.aspx) detailing many of the new features in ASP.NET 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

There are many, but I will suggest that the more exciting things coming are the maturing technologies that I use. Project Astoria which changed to ADO.NET dataservices and then has had two CTP releases out of band will finally be brought into step with .NET 4.0 and be called WCF dataservices.

A restful data access layer with language integrated query and the power of anonymous and instance methods and type inference means you can write things like this semi psuedo code, with a lot of the problems ironed out and a lot of good forum knowledge:

```
Button.Click += new EventHandler((o,e) =>{DG.ItemsSource DataContext.tblUsers.Where(f=>f.active ==true;);
```

Don't mention MVVM or inefficiencies etc, but I believe this code does on one line what would take a fair few to do in .NET 2.0